# Integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$ depends on $n\bmod{4}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to find the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$ by following the hints in Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, Exercise 4.20. Here are the steps he suggests to take:

> a) reduce to the case where $n$ is square-free.
>
> b) show that we are really looking for the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$, call this $R$. Show that for any $z=a+b\sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$ the minimal polynomial $q(x)$ for $z$ is $q(x)=x^2-2ax+a^2-b^2n$, and prove that $q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ iff $z\in R$.
>
> c) show that if $z\in R$ then $a\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. If $a=0$ show that $z\in R$ iff $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $a=\frac{1}{2}$ show that $z\in R$ iff $b\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> d) Conclude that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ if $n\not\equiv1\bmod{4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}]$ if $n\equiv1\bmod{4}$.

My question is, how does part d) follow from part c)? I can't see a way to do this. I have shown a), b), and c), but I'm not sure what $\bmod 4$ has to do with anything. Any hints?

Comment: you need $-2a$ and $a^2-b^2n$ to be in $\mathbb Z$, right?  note that $n\not\equiv0\bmod4$ if $n$ is square-free

Comment: yeah and I showed that if $z\in R$ then $-2a,a^2-b^2n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $-2a\in\mathbb Z$ means $a=m/2, m\in\mathbb Z$; then $a^2-nb^2\in\mathbb Z$ means $\frac{m^2}4-nb^2\in\mathbb Z$ or $m^2-4nb^2\in4\mathbb Z$, and remember that squares are congruent to $0$ or $1\pmod4$

Comment: I see that $m^2-4nb^2\in 4\mathbb{Z}$, and I know that since $n\not\equiv0\text{ mod }4$, we must have $n\equiv 2\text{ mod }4$ or $n\equiv 3\text{ mod }4$ in the case of $n\not\equiv1\text{ mod }4$. But how can I go from here?

Comment: say $b=2s\in\mathbb Z$; then it's $m^2-ns^2\in 4\mathbb Z$; since $k^2\equiv0$ or $1\pmod4$, we could have $m^2,s^2\equiv1\bmod4$ if $n\equiv1\pmod4$, but if $n\equiv2$ or $3\pmod4$, then we must have $m^2,s^2\equiv0\pmod4$, i.e, $m,s$ are even; i.e., $a,b$ are integers, not half-integers

Comment: I see. So then we would have $a+b\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$, proving the claim when $n\not\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$. So is the other case similar? When $n\equiv1\text{ mod }4$, we have $m^2,s^2\equiv1\text{ mod }4$, yes?

Comment: for $n\equiv1$ we have $a$ and $b$ are integers or $a$ and $b$ are half odd integers; for $n\equiv2,3$ we must have $a,b$ integers

Comment: Interesting. It almost seems as though your method removes the necessity of part c).